# Nucleotide Sequence

Tags: bacteriology, nucleotide

So i am from an IT and my sis who is doing medicine asked for my help on this question i have no clue where to start actually. Please Help. So the question is:

> What is the nucleotide sequence for vibrio cholerae bacteria or
> treponema pallidum bacteria? or any other related bacteria?

After the nucleotide sequence is got, is possible to use BLAST (https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi) to align and compare a query DNA sequence with a database of sequences?

Please correct me wherever i'm wrong and thanks for helping

Comment: I think this is more suited to [SE.bioinformatics](http://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yes it is possible. That's what BLAST is for. The nucleotide sequences can easily be found by searching the NCBI [Nucleotide](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/) database.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 102 genomes of the bacterium *Vibrio cholerae* that have been sequenced. For example, *Vibrio cholerae* 01 biovar El Tor strain N16961 has two chromosomes spanning 4,033,464 bp in which its ORFs code for 3,827 proteins and 122 RNAs. [Check here](https://vibrio.biocyc.org) The DNA is available at NCBI as entries [AE003852](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AE003852.1?report=fasta) and [AE003853](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AE003853.1?report=fasta).
There are at least 11 sequenced genomes of *Treponema pallidum*. For example, [Strain Fribourg-Blanc](https://biocyc.org/GCF_000387485/organism-summary) has 1,004 protein genes and 54 RNA genes distributed over 1,140,481 bp genome. [NCBI DNA sequence entry NC_021179.1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_021179.1?report=fasta)
I suppose one may align multiple sequences of whole genomes if that's what intended, but I do not advise it unless one is ready to curate the results. Instead, I recommend studying a given open reading frame using its DNA sequence, or better yet its corresponding protein sequence. BLAST should be quite helpful in finding similar sequences to compare to.